# Importing Pandoc markdown into Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, pandoc

I'm looking to important content from Pandoc markdown into Mediawiki.

What is the normal way to import into mediawiki? This page: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps#How_to_import.3F talks about importing XML dumps.

But is the best way to import, to convert markdown into xml in the right format?

Or is it better to import directly into the database?

Are there any other extensions out there? I'm trying to ascertain the common methods for doing this and whether I need to write something myself or not.

Comment: It would help if your requirements were mentioned in the question (what kind of and what size of content, do you know the MediaWiki-side details such as page names or does the import process need to figure that out, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Directly messing with the database is never a good idea, and XML is primarily meant to import dumpfiles exported from other wikis (although it is not terribly hard to construct it manually). For simple cases, the easiest way is using [edit.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Edit.php).